# Popen example that I do not understand

Tags: ruby, popen

I have a basic understanding of `popen` before now but it seems it has changed completely. 
Please refer the example to know why?

```
# process.rb

IO.popen("ruby test_ex.rb","w") do |io|
   io.write("#{Process.pid} hello")
   io.close_write
   ## this does not work.
   ##io.readlines
end
```

```
## text_ex.rb
def readWrite
  @string = gets()
  puts "#{Process.pid} -- #{@string}"
end
readWrite
```

Now I understand in `write` mode the `STDOUT`(of `popen.rb`) will be `writable end` of the **pipe** and `STDIN` (of `text_ex.rb`) will be the `readable end` of the **pipe**.

All is good here.

But let see the other example

```
  my_text = IO.popen("ssh user@host 'bash'", "w+")
  my_text.write("hostname")
  my_text.close_write
  my_rtn = my_text.readlines.join('\n')
  my_text.close
  puts my_rtn
```

Ok, now what is different over here?
 The `popen` start a child process(i.e `ssh`) send the `hostname`.

Now, I fail to understand how does the `STDOUT` of the child process(i.e ssh) is available to the parent process i.e how does the `readlines` work over here and does not work in my earlier example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the second argument to `popen`: `"w"` versus `"w+"`. You can read more [here in the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode):

> "w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
>        to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
>
> "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
>        or creates a new file for reading and writing.

The notion of "truncating" doesn't really apply to pipes, but the fact that you need read-write mode does.

Comment: Can you help how does it work. Last I read `Pipes are unidirectional ` so how does the output of the subprocess is available here?

Comment: I suppose `popen` opens two pipes, one for writing to the process's stdin and one for reading from the process's stdout.